# OpenSilver and Dispatcher.CheckAccess

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, dispatcher, opensilver

I am working on porting an old Silverlight application over to OpenSilver. Throughout the Silverlight code there are `if( <control>.CheckAccess())...` to make sure to be on the correct thread.  Is my impression this check is no longer needed in OpenSilver?  In other words, the following Silverlight code can be transformed into the following:

*Yes, **I know that callback-based async methods have been replaced with awaitable tasks.**  I am going to ask some questions about that conversion in my next question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297658/converting-wcf-web-service-calls-from-callback-based-async-method-to-awaitable-t).  This question is exclusively about the fate of the Dispatcher.CheckAccess*

Silverlight:

```
private void GetNextImage()
{
    var cmc = ServiceFactories.CreateCartManager();
    cmc.getSlideImageCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (imageGrid.CheckAccess())
        {
            cmc_getSlideImageCompleted(s, e);
        }
        else
        {
            var args = new object[] { s, e };
            imageGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new getSlideImageCompletedDelegate(cmc_getSlideImageCompleted),
                args);
        }
    };

    var lastTime = SystemSettings.GetInstance().SlideShowData.LastImageTime;
    cmc.getSlideImageAsync(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastTime) ? null : lastTime);
}
```

to OpenSilver:

```
private void GetNextImage()
{
    var cmc = ServiceFactories.CreateCartManager();
    cmc.getSlideImageCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
            cmc_getSlideImageCompleted(s, e);
    };

    var lastTime = SystemSettings.GetInstance().SlideShowData.LastImageTime;
    cmc.getSlideImageAsync(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastTime) ? null : lastTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `Dispatcher.CheckAccess` since `OpenSilver` is currently single threaded (it uses mono.wasm runtime which doesn't support threads yet).

However, OpenSilver keeps compatibility with Silverlight, so if you have an old Silverlight code which does the check you can just keep it (it will always return true when running in Browser).

Comment: Thank you.  I had a few failed attempts to port the code, with this bit of insight I will give it another try.