# Converting WCF Web service calls from callback-based async method to awaitable task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, wcf-ria-services, opensilver

I am converting over an old Silverlight application that used callback-based WCF Web Services over to OpenSilver that is using awaitable task based WCF Web Services.  I am trying to figure out how to handle the error conditions.  Here is the callback-based code:

```
private void GetNextImage()
{
    var cmc = ServiceFactories.CreateCartManager();
    cmc.getSlideImageCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        cmc_getSlideImageCompleted(s, e);
    };

    var lastTime = SystemSettings.GetInstance().SlideShowData.LastImageTime;
    cmc.getSlideImageAsync(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastTime) ? null : lastTime);
}

void cmc_getSlideImageCompleted(object sender, getSlideImageCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        GetNextImage();
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        var errMsg = new ErrorWindow("Error while trying to get next image in slide show:", msg);
        errMsg.Show();
    }
    else if (e.Result == null)
    {
        // There are no images in the slide show right now.
    }
    else
    {
        // we have an image!!!!
        var imageData = e.Result.imageData;
        // <the rest of the code>
    }
}
```

I know that GetNextImage() should look like this:

```
private async Task GetNextImage()
{
    var cmc = ServiceFactories.CreateCartManager();

    var lastTime = SystemSettings.GetInstance().SlideShowData.LastImageTime;
    var result = await cmc.getSlideImageAsync(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastTime) ? null : lastTime);
    cmc_getSlideImageCompleted(result);
}

void cmc_getSlideImageCompleted(getSlideImageResponse e)
{
    ...
}
```

The question is, what happened to e.Cancelled, e.Error, and e.Result?  How do I account for that lower level errors now?

Comment: The `getSlideImageCompletedEventArgs` class holds the event data for the Completed event.`e.Cancelled` means getSlideImage is cancelled, and then re-executes GetNextImage();`e.Error` means there is a problem with getSlideImage;`e.Result `represents the result of getSlideImage.

Comment: Maybe you can keep using getSlideImageCompletedEventArgs class or try using [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch#taskwhenall-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happened to e.Cancelled, e.Error, and e.Result?

#### `e.Cancelled`

If you have an async method (in your case the `cmc.getSlideImageAsync`) then this can be cancelled through a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-6.0). Inside this method if you repeatedly check where the cancellation has been requested or not (via the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`) then it will throw a `OperationCanceledException` (or a derived class).

So, the equivalent of `e.Cancelled` is this:

```
getSlideImageResponse response;
try
{
   response = await cmc.getSlideImageAsync(..., cancellationToken);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
{
   //if(e.Cancelled) logic goes here
}
```

#### `e.Error`

If your async method fails for whatever reason then it will populate the underlying `Task`'s [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception?view=net-6.0) property.

```
Task<getSlideImageResponse> getTask = cmc.getSlideImageAsync(...);
getTask.Wait(); //BAD PRACTICE, JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES
if(getTask.Exception != null)
{
   //if(e.Error != null) logic goes here
}
```

The above code is suboptimal since the `.Wait` is a blocking call and can cause deadlock. The recommended approach is to use `await`. This operator can retrieve the `.Exception` property from the `Task` and can throw it again:

```
getSlideImageResponse response;
try
{
   response = await cmc.getSlideImageAsync(...);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //if(e.Error != null) logic goes here
}
```

#### `e.Result`

This property was populated only if the method was not cancelled or did not fail. The same is true here:

```
getSlideImageResponse response;
try
{
   response = await cmc.getSlideImageAsync(..., cancellationToken);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException ocex)
{
   //if(e.Cancelled) logic goes here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //if(e.Error != null) logic goes here
}

//if(e.Result != null) logic goes here
```